# Combinatorics, Hall's marriage theorem for bipartite graphs, where 2 vertices cannot be connected to more than one common vertex from the other side

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

I have a problem I'm trying to solve. the problem is: given Bipartite graph $G=(A\cup B,E)$, where  $\vert A\vert=\vert B\vert=n>100$. and all edges are from $A$ to $B$ (all edges are symmetric), additionaly, lets assume that $\forall a_1\neq a_2$ in $A$ ,
$$ \vert \{ b\in B : \{ a_1,b\},\{a_2,b \} \in E \} \vert \leq 1.$$ (in the original problem I had to prove it, which I actually did, So its a given now, you can also assume that the same applies with $2$ vertices of $B$ and one vertex from $A$ if you need, just like the topic mentions ).
Furthermore, the degree of every vertex in A is at least $n\over4$, prove that there is a perfect matching in the graph. any hints or solutions would be great, thanks in advance!.
edit: Hey, I might've done a mistake by not telling an important information, the original question included the following assumption: assume that for each $a_1 \neq a_2 $ in $A$ and for each $b_1 \neq b_2$ in $B$ at least one of the pairs $$\{a_1,b_1\},\{a_1,b_2\},\{a_2,b_1\},\{a_2,b_2 \} $$ isn't an edge in the graph.

Comment: Try to find the minimum size of the neighborood of one vertex, then the minimum on two vertices, and generalize (with recurrence). Be careful, when the size of your subset is big enough, the recurrence will change.

Comment: That is strange. Consider, for example, $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5 \in A$. As their degrees are at least $\frac{n}{4}$, at least one of the $a_i$ , $i \in[4]$, is such that $|N(a_i)\cap N(a_5)| \geq \frac{n}{16}>1$. Isn't that a contradiction with your other hypothesis?

Answer (score 1):

Your theorem is vacuously true, since there do not exist any bipartite graphs satisfying your conditions.

Assume that a graph exists satisfying all of your conditions. On the one hand, your graph has at least $n/4$ edges for each of the $n$ vertices in $A$, so at least $n\times (n/4)$ edges in total. On the other hand, your graph has no cycles of length $3$ or  $4$, which implies that it has at most $(2n)^{3/2}/2$ edges. For a proof of the general fact that a graph with $|V|$ vertices and no $3$-cycles or $4$-cycles has at most $\frac12|V|^{3/2}$ edges, see the citation at the end.

Since $n\times (n/4)\le |E|\le (2n)^{3/2}/2$, we conclude $n\le 32$, contradicting $n\ge 100$.

> Garnick, David K., Kwong, Y. H. Harris, Lazebnik, Felix, *Extremal graphs without three-cycles or four-cycles*. J. Graph Theory 17 (1993), no. 5, 633–645. http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190170511